# angular6 loading issue with opensocial.googleusercontent.com

Tags: firebase-authentication, angular-material, angular6

Deployed angular 6 app (using angular material) in ngnix.

Login page navigation has no issue.  Using fire-base auth and post login authentication, navigating to the login successful page but getting the below error shown in console and page load stops (hangs) here.
Page load starts again if i resize the window.

This error is coming from www-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/rpc/rpc.v.js, not sure what is causing this error

```
rpc.v.js:23 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined
    at Object.init (rpc.v.js:23)
    at Object.init (rpc.v.js:276)
    at rpc.v.js:284
```

My index file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tradingapp9</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">



  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- This is for google authentication -->
<!--script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script-->
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<!-- This is for google authentication -->
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Not getting anyinput from google search